# Personal OneDrive Audio Facet returns null for various audio files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the v1.0 Graph API to query a Personal OneDrive account. In the Graph Explorer, I make the following GET request for two separate audio files (one is an mp3 and the other is an m4a):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}
```

For both files, this returns all of the default properties (Name, ID, Size, etc.). However, it does not return the Audio Facet as one would expect. The mp3 file for sure has metadata such as Album, Artist, and Genre amongst other things.

Is the Audio Facet only attached to certain audio file extensions? Might this be related to a permissions setting?

Comment: If you find the files over at https://onedrive.com and bring up the information pane for each do you see the expected metadata? Short answer is that MP3s and M4A should definitely have metadata appearing by default.

Comment: In the information pane, I see Type, Modified, Path, Size. There are two images (one is a png and the other is a jpg) in the same folder and an Image Facet is returned for those. The information pane for both images shows the same as the audio files (Type, Modified, Path, Size).

Comment: Ok, so definitely no metadata (i.e. it's not an API issue). Do you know when these files were uploaded?

Comment: February 21, 2017

Comment: Hi @apatino, do you mind providing the ids for the two files you're seeing issues with? If you'd rather not give them publicly let me know and I'll start a private chat.

Comment: We can start a private chat.